# C#. Получение кадра видео с веб-камеры с помощью AForge

Tags: c#, web-camera, aforge

Необходимо получать кадры видео с веб-камеры и производить с этими кадрами некоторые действия. Применяю такой код:

```
FilterInfoCollection videosources = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        //Check if atleast one video source is available
        if (videosources != null)
        {
            var videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videosources[0].MonikerString);
            try
            {
                if (videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length > 0) <------ Падение
                {
                    string highestSolution = "0;0";
                    //Search for the highest resolution
                    for (int i = 0; i < videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width > Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[0]))
                            highestSolution = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width.ToString() + ";" + i.ToString();
                    }
                    videoSource.VideoResolution = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[1])];
                }
            }
            catch { }

            videoSource.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);
  videoSource.Start();
```

На строке падения возникает ошибка:

```
System.ApplicationException: 'Unsupported format found.'
```

Подключена камера Logitech c270 на Windows 10 c последними драйверами. Вопрос: почему я даже не могу получить свойство `VideoCapabilities`. Не говоря уже о том, что если закомментировать весь блок `try-catch` валится та же ошибка?
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: на каком этапе ошибка? если закоментить

Comment: Скорее всего при получении нового фрейма в `videoSource_NewFrame`. Потому что на пол секунды появляется форма, и сразу падает